# Capybara check if class changed after click

Tags: capybara, rspec-rails

How can I check if the css class was added to the div after the button click?

I have a button with class "btn-success" and a modal form which by default doesn't have "show" class, but after clicking on the button the "show" class is added to the modal.

My test:

```
it 'shows up popup with form' do
  modal_window = page.find('#data-modal')

  expect(modal_window[:class]).not_to include('show')

  page.find('.btn-success').click

  expect(modal_window[:class]).to include('show')
end
```

My Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'webmock'

  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To do exactly what you're asking the easiest solution would be something like

```
it 'shows up popup with form' do
  expect(page).not_to have_css('#data-modal.show')
  page.find('.btn-success').click
  expect(page).to have_css('#data-modal.show')
end
```

However you really shouldn't be testing for the existence of specific classes in feature tests. Instead you should be testing that the modal actually appears. Since this is JS driven behavior it would mean making sure your test is running with a JS capable driver, making sure you haven't set `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements` to false,   and then doing

```
it 'shows up popup with form' do
  # Should initially be hidden so won't be found
  expect(page).not_to have_css('#data-modal')
  page.find('.btn-success').click
  # Should now be found
  expect(page).to have_css('#data-modal')
end
```